# How to convert Java AES ECB Encryption Code to Nodejs

Tags: java, node.js, aes, cryptojs, ecb

I have code in java for encryption

```
public String encrypt() throws Exception {
    String data = "Hello World";
    String secretKey = "j3u8ue8xmrhsth59";
    byte[] keyValue = secretKey.getBytes();
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES");
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(StringUtils.getBytesUtf8(data));
    String encryptedValue = Base64.encodeBase64String(encVal);
    return encryptedValue;
}
```

It returns same value ( eg5pK6F867tyDhBdfRkJuA== ) as the [tool here](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption)
[image]

I converted the code to Nodejs (crypto)

```
var crypto = require('crypto')

encrypt(){
      var data = "Hello World"
      var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-ecb','j3u8ue8xmrhsth59')
      var crypted = cipher.update(data,'utf-8','base64')
      crypted += cipher.final('base64')
      return crypted;
}
```

But this is giving a different value ( POixVcNnBs3c8mwM0lcasQ== )

How to get same value from both?
What am I missing?

Comment: [See the param name and paras 4 to 6 of the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options). Use createCipheriv, even though the IV for ECB is empty (`new Buffer(0)`). Also, using a small set of printable characters for the key is weak, and using ECB is usually insecure, but those are topics for a different Stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to dave now I am getting same result both for Java and Nodejs/JavaScript

```
var crypto = require('crypto')

encrypt(){
      var data = "Hello World"
      var iv = new Buffer(0);
       const key = 'j3u8ue8xmrhsth59'
      var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-ecb',new Buffer(key),new Buffer(iv))
      var crypted = cipher.update(data,'utf-8','base64')
      crypted += cipher.final('base64')
      return crypted;
}
```