# (Java to Javascript) javax.crypto.Cipher equivalent code in Nodejs Crypto Javascript

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, encryption-symmetric, javax.crypto

I'm trying to convert below java code into nodejs.

```java
    private static String TRANS_MODE = "Blowfish";

    private static String BLOWFISH_KEY = "BLOWFISH_KEY";

    public static String encrypt(String password) throws Exception {

    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(BLOWFISH_KEY.getBytes("Windows-31J"),TRANS_MODE);
    Cipher cipher;
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANS_MODE);

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
    byte[] passByte;
    passByte = cipher.doFinal(password.getBytes("Windows-31J"));


    return new String(Hex.encodeHex(passByte));

    }
```

Here is what I was able to figure out-

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

function encrypt(password)  
  var fcKey = "BLOWFISH_KEY";
  var cipher = crypto.createCipher('BF-CBC', fcKey, "");
  var encrypted = cipher.update(password,'ascii','hex');
  encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
return encrypted;
```

I'm not able to get same output. For example if

password= "password01"

Java Code output - fe0facbf8d458adaa47c5fe430cbc0ad

Nodejs Code output - ae5e8238c929b5716566e97fa35efb9b

Can someone help me figure out the problem ??

Comment: Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57447707/how-to-convert-java-aes-ecb-encryption-code-to-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

Notice that `crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password[, options])` is deprecated and should not be used.

Where the `SecretKeySpec(..)` in java takes a binary key as input, the createCipher(..) in js takes a "password" as input, and behind the scene tries to derive a binary key using MD5. So your actually key used in the two programs ends up being different. The js methode 
also tries to derive an IV from the password, which is bad practice and different from your java code.

In js you need to use the `crypto.createCipheriv()` instead. And when you are at it, you also need to consider if an iv is needed - both in Java and in js.

Comment: Java crypto when you specify only an algorithm like 'BLOWFISH' (instead of a 'transform' = algorithm/mode/padding) actually uses **ECB** and PKCS5-style padding, whereas nodejs crypto uses OpenSSL which defaults if necessary to CBC (and PKCS5). ECB has no IV and also is insecure for nearly all purposes (see numerous Qs about this on security.SX and crypto.SX); CBC does require unique and unpredictable IV.